# Form Validation Requiring Enter to Continue

Tags: javascript, validation

Some simple form validation seems to require hitting *Enter* once the correct value has been added before allowing the visitor to move on. Any way to eliminate that? Here is an example of one of them.

```
// Makes sure that the email looks valid and contains an @, a . and at least two characters after the dot
function checkEMail(obj) {
    var emailFilter =  /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/ ;
    var illegalChars = /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\"\[\]]/ ;
    if (!emailFilter.test(obj)) {
        obj.style.background = 'Yellow';
        alert('Please enter a valid email address, then press Enter to continue.');
    } else if (!illegalChars.test(obj)) {
        obj.style.background = 'Yellow';
        alert('The email address contains illegal characters.');
    } else {
        obj.style.background = 'White';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a return to `true` in your "happy flow" in the validation function.

```
// Makes sure that the email looks valid and contains an @, a . and at least two characters after the dot
function checkEMail(obj) {
    var emailFilter =  /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/ ;
    var illegalChars = /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\"\[\]]/ ;
    if (!emailFilter.test(obj)) {
        obj.style.background = 'Yellow';
        alert('Please enter a valid email address, then press Enter to continue.');
    } else if (!illegalChars.test(obj)) {
        obj.style.background = 'Yellow';
        alert('The email address contains illegal characters.');
    } else {
        obj.style.background = 'White';
        return true;
    }
}
```

Script with similar type of logic, working example:

```js
function execute(a) {
  if(a === 1) {
    alert("1");
  } else if (a === 2) {
    alert("2");
  } else {
    console.log('lele');
    return true;
  }
}

execute(3);
```

Comment: That sounds exactly like the answer and I was sure it was something very simple and obvious that I had missed. I am a back-end programmer so know little about Javascript but can cobble together simple things. However, I notice that the field does not seem to reach its "happy flow" state and remains yellow so even after adding return true; it needs the Enter to continue.

Comment: That's because some of the if conditions are being completed and entered in their flows, showing the alert and then, you need to hit Enter to continue. I added a similar logic script to help to clarify this.

Comment: So how do I get around it? Hitting Enter is not practical so perhaps the Regex itself is faulty. Even if the field is filled properly the first time, it's yellow gives the alert and requires Enter to move on. I am calling it from the form field using onchange="checkEMail(this);" so perhaps this is not the proper way to do it?

Comment: I would check the regex if you are sure the email you are trying to validate is right.

Comment: It seems to have the same issue on all the functions and some have extremely simplistic regex.